# Output with multiple inputs needed/given[Python3]

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a program that asks the user how many items they want. The user can enter a maximum of 5. I have also created a text file with 5 items containing a unique code, price, and name of product.

Lets say the user enters 3, it will prompt the user to enter a code, 3 separate times. Afterwards it will ask how many of each item the user wants. My program then prints out the code, name of the product, price, quantity needed, and total price.

Now this is the problem I have: My code only does this for the last item given. If I enter the code for chicken it only outputs the list for chicken and not the other products before.

code:

```
    while True:
    itemsneeded = input("How many items do you need?")
    if itemsneeded.isnumeric() and int(itemsneeded) <= 5:
        break
    GTIN=''

count=0
while count<int(itemsneeded):
            GTIN=(input('Please enter all GTIN-8 for all items'))
            if GTIN.isnumeric() and len(GTIN)==8:
                Num0=int(GTIN[0])*3
                Num1=int(GTIN[1])
                Num2=int(GTIN[2])*3
                Num3=int(GTIN[3])
                Num4=int(GTIN[4])*3
                Num5=int(GTIN[5])
                Num6=int(GTIN[6])*3
                Num7=int(GTIN[7])
                total2=(Num0+Num1+Num2+Num3+Num4+Num5+Num6+Num7)
            if total2 % 10 == 0:
                print(GTIN)
                if GTIN in open('read_it.txt').read():
                    print('entered GTIN is valid')
                else:
                    print('The code entered is invalid')
                    print('Please renter this code')

            count+=1
        else:
            print("The entered GTIN-8 codes are incorrect")
count=0
while count<int(itemsneeded):
    quantity=input('Please enter the Quantity needed:')
    if quantity.isnumeric() and int(quantity)<10:
        count+=1
    else:
        break
```

From here it's just a mess, I have tried to print out the items from the text file according to the code given:

```
if GTIN=='86947367':
        with open("read_it.txt") as fp:
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            total1=int(quantity)*int(next(fp))
    if GTIN=='86947367':
        with open("read_it.txt") as fp:
            next(fp)
            print('86947367'.rstrip(),next(fp).rstrip(),quantity.rstrip(),next(fp).rstrip(),'Â£',total1)
    if GTIN=='78364721':
        with open("read_it.txt") as fp:
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            total1=int(quantity)*int(next(fp))
    if GTIN=='78364721':
        with open("read_it.txt") as fp:
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            print('78364721'.rstrip(),next(fp).rstrip(),quantity.rstrip(),next(fp).rstrip(),'Â£',total1)
    if GTIN=='35619833':
        with open("read_it.txt") as fp:
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            total1=int(quantity)*int(next(fp))
    if GTIN=='35619833':
        with open("read_it.txt") as fp:
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            print('35619833'.rstrip(),next(fp).rstrip(),quantity.rstrip(),next(fp).rstrip(),'Â£',total1)
    if GTIN=='84716491':
        with open("read_it.txt") as fp:
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            total1=int(quantity)*int(next(fp))
    if GTIN=='84716491':
        with open("read_it.txt") as fp:
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            print('84716491'.rstrip(),next(fp).rstrip(),quantity.rstrip(),next(fp).rstrip(),'Â£',total1)
    if GTIN=='46389121':
        with open("read_it.txt") as fp:
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            total1=int(quantity)*int(next(fp))
    if GTIN=='46389121':
        with open("read_it.txt") as fp:
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            next(fp)
            print('46389121'.rstrip(),next(fp).rstrip(),quantity.rstrip(),next(fp).rstrip(),'Â£',total1)
```

I'd like to know how to deal with multiple user inputs and use them to output the needed information from the text file.

text file:https://mega.nz/#!GQ0BhTKD!KsC4ZhFW7LJuwXXkJFyjdS9geiiJjaoUy6CAbuD6qkI

Comment: please,format your code properly - for python it's crucial

Comment: the indentation is correct.

Comment: It is no way the indentation is correct. On the second line of your second code block the "with" line is over indented for sure.

Comment: I've edited your post to improve readability and clarity. I've also removed some redundant text to help with the flow. If you would, please move (a sample of) the contents of the externally hosted text file into the body of your post. Thanks!